# CSS keeps breaking

Tags: html, css

I'm using a template I found for my portfolio, everything works perfectly for a while then suddenly the CSS breaks & there's no styling on the page. I keep getting these 3 errors in the CSS file even though I am NOT editing the CSS file at all. I can't post 2 screenshots but the first 2 errors I'm getting is

`ul, ol {padding: 0; webkit-padding: 0; moz-padding: 0;}`

with the squiggly lines under webkit-padding and moz-padding. The screenshot is the other error. The template is using bootstrap & my browser is chrome. Thank you so much.

[image: This is one of the errors I'm getting]

Comment: Did you try `-webkit` instead of `webkit` for the first one and `-moz`?

Comment: thanks so much, that got rid of the error for those 2 but still no styling

Comment: You're providing invalid properties as all the properties shown don't need prefixing (might look at [shouldiprefix.com](www.shouldiprefix.com)) for reference, but even then that shouldn't "break" your css as the invalid properties should just get ignored.  I suspect your culprit is elsewhere.

Comment: But I don't think you would need those prefixes unless you are targeting for older browsers.

Comment: Thanks so much Chris, I suspect the same because my terminal was showing those errors and the styling would still load just fine but then it just suddenly stops.

Comment: Do you have a public instance where the behavior can be seen / recreated? If so it's probably some inane thing that's an easy fix but would help to see it to debug.

Comment: @m4n0 yeah I'm guessing the template is older, I'm being lazy by using a template I know, I just didn't want to spend so much time on a portfolio while doing other things.

Comment: @ChrisW.  I just stopped my server and restarted it and the styling came back, lol *throws hands in the air* Idk...but thank you so much !! I really appreciate it.

Comment: @DollyDesir yep, remember your css is usually cached. So it can be a sanity saver to use an icognito window or have dev tools open with the option to clear cache on refresh option on so you don't get stale caches, or provide a version arg on your file strings to force a new version retrieval each time. Have a great weekend!

Comment: @ChrisW. I will definitely keep that in mind, thank you !